# Trying to make a fetch 'POST' but it is only returning the id to the json file

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

I am trying to make a fetch 'POST' to a localhost:3000 server, I am collecting 'user' information like email and name from a form and I need to send it back to the server. I am having issues getting that data sent back to the server, instead what is happening now, the only data getting sent back to the server are the id's and not the input data

```js
const doc = document.querySelector('#email-container')

function newestEmail(){
  doc.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let object = {
      name: e.target.inputName.value,
      email: e.target.inputEmail.value
    }
    postEmail(object)
  })
}

function postEmail(object) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
  
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/Emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    header: 
    {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(object)
   
  })
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(eachEmail => eachEmail)
}
```

```html
<form id="email-container">
      <h2 id="form">
        EMAIL SIGN UP
      </h2>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name..." id="inputName" />
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email..." id="inputEmail" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitButton" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi, i think your code is meant to say `headers` and not `header`.

Can you give more information on what you mean by `the only data getting sent back to the server are the id's and not the input data`? There's not enough information to answer.

Comment: WOW, it was supposed to say headers, I appreciate you, everything is working as it should!

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` api takes `headers`. Your code has `header` which would be a typo.